# IBM Worklight - How to access JSON sent using an adapter in server-side PHP?

Tags: php, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am developing a hybrid application in IBM Worklight.

In my app, there is a registration form. I have a requirement: After the user registers with the app, the form data will be sent to an external server in JSON format using an HTTP adapter.

In the external server,

- How to access the JSON data sent using the HTTP adapter in a PHP file? and
- How to send back a response in the same JSON format?

Please give demo codes of both HTTP adapter and server side PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client code:

```
function callAdapter(){

    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'MyAdapter',
            procedure : 'MyAdapterProcedure',
            parameters : [username, password]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : adapterSuccessCallback,
        onFailure : adapterFailureCallback
    });
}
```

Adapter implementation:

```
function myAdapterProcedure(username, password) {

    var credentials = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : "/myPHPscript.php",
        parameters: {credentials: credentials}
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
        $jsonObj = $_POST['credentials'];
        $credentials = json_decode($jsonObj)

        // sanitation, database calls, etc

        $returnDict = array();
        $returnDict["success"] = true;
        echo json_encode($returnDict);
?>
```

Comment: Can you post Idan's solution here and mark it as the answered solution? Or were you referring to my answer?

Comment: I think you just misread the username on the answer  :)    The solution above was posted by me. You can see the username at the bottom of the answer. What you're seeing is that Idan edited your question, which is why his username and avatar are shown above. Also, you can hit the green checkmark under the voting arrows to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Its my mistake jnortey. Thanks for answering my question, obviously, I am referring to your answer.

Comment: Also can you tell me now how to access json data in php. I googled and find to access json data use $credentials->email type syntax. but , however, the values are not storing in database and also not echoing, although the values are sent back correctly to the app. from where the request is made.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to make sure the correct answer was present so that others who have the same problem could find it. In PHP, the -> notation is used to access class variables or class functions. The 'credentials' object is an associative array, so you should access it using $credentials['email'].

Comment: I tried $credentials['email'] but its not working, I am trying to store decoded values in the database but nothing happens. To debug, i echoed values but nothing prints, what would be the problem?

Comment: Make the first line your php script var_dump($_POST) and view the output. If you don't see your credentials information somewhere in that dump, then the information isn't properly being sent to your script. If you do see it, then theres just something wrong with the way you are trying to get the information from the $_POST array.

Comment: I tried var_dump($_POST) and the output is size = 0, but if i just sent the values after decoding and encoding to json format, these values are received by the app which made request.

Comment: I would need to see more of your source code to debug this. Can you try opening another question and linking it here? Stack overflow frowns upon continuing discussions in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: Problem continued in another question as you recommend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596166/echo-posted-json-data-in-server-php