# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - JavaScript not executing in a jQuery Mobile multipage app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight Studio version_6.0.0.20130926-2018.

In my app I am using the jQuery Mobile framework.
My problem is that when I try to load a `data-role="page"` using `$.mobile.changePage`, the  page is not refreshed by itself. When I refresh this page, the JavaScript code is not working.

Instead, I get the following errors:

```
 ReferenceError: WLJQ is not defined profile.html:11
 TypeError: $ is undefined jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js:28
 ReferenceError: $ is not defined profile.js:3
 ReferenceError: WL is not defined
```

The `$.mobile.changePage` code:

```
//redirect to profile
    function redirectToProfile(profileId){
        if(profileId == null || profileId == ""){
            $("#failMessage").fadeIn();
        }
        else{
            var dataurl = '?profileID='+profileId;
            $("#failMessage").fadeOut(200, function(){$("#loginSuccess").fadeIn(function(){$.mobile.changePage('pages/profile.html'+dataurl, {reloadPage : true,transition: "slide"});});});

        }
    }
});
```

How to solve this in Worklight?

Comment: Remove `reloadPage` as you force to load entire HTML tag. If the loaded page has no essential libraries loaded in head tag, it'll fail to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you created another HTML page that you navigated to. It is not the right way to do navigation when using Worklight. Worklight is a single-page application!, so you need to use a div element that switches the content instead of navigating between pages.
More information regarding this can be found here:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing is if I make a single html file with all the divs inside this, it might work slow. Also the content may not be organised. What i tried to do is that: I have a first html registration page- consists of two data-role pages related to login and register of user and other html profile page with other data-role pages related to his profile requirements. I think this approach is comparatively easy to manage. otherwise all registration and profile divs in a single html file can be chaos.

Comment: Please take a look at the multiple page sample app project provided by Worklight: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#client-basics

Comment: Ok! I tried to understand the sample code provided in the IBM site.

Comment: You can also take a look at this pastebin featuring a very basic app using jQuery Mobile in Worklight, with header+content+footer and buttons where the content is replaced with content from other HTML files: http://pastebin.com/mMaAu5wL --- this code is using the same page load approach as in the training module and sample that Shmulik and I linked you to.

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage()` loads page via Ajax and places it inside body or _pageContainer_. I don't know how worklight reacts with this, but it has something to do with it, not JQM.

Comment: Yes, I would instead use a container div where you simply `$("#container).load("somepage.html")` the content into it. This is also what the training module suggests.

Comment: @IdanAdar note that `pageContainer` option used in `$.mobile.changePage` is no longer used in jQM 1.4. I _guess_ that `reloadPage` is the problem. Could you please test?

Comment: Is it deprecated, not removed. It's still there. And it doesn't matter, as can been seen in the quetion: jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 is being used.

Comment: @IdanAdar _deprecated and will be removed on 1.5_. What if the user decides to upgrade, now or in the future?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this, because you can bundle jQuery/Mobile in your Worklight app, so as long as you use code that is compatible with the version of jQuery/Mobile that you include inyour app, you are good to go. If you decide to upgrade it in a future release you will of course need to update the code; In this question the developer uses jQuery Mobile v1.3.2 so there is no problem with this code.

Comment: My problem is solved, i just put the script tag inside the div tag with data-role=page as it is the only part loaded when called using $.mobile.changePage.                                                              Also, i want to know about .load() function that can we use transitions with it as we used the transitions with $.mobile.changePage.